# Attach a "temporary" property to a POCO for WPF View binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

The scenario is this:

A *ViewModel* has a list of [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)  which eventually needs to be displayed by a *view*, for example a *GridView*. Let's say the mechanism to display is to use `ObservableCollection<Person>` as one of the ViewModel's properties.

Now, the View needs a checkbox to indicate selected or unselected for each Person.

The solution I have in mind, is to wrap the Person POCO (I cannot change this class) by making a new throw-away class (e.g. *PersonVM*) that mirrors the *Person* class, implements *INotifyPropertyChanged*, then adding a new property called "Selected" that notifies changes.

So once the *ViewModel* receives the `List<Person>` during contruction for example, I will loop thru this list, creating a new instance of PersonVM for every Person, then adding it to the `ObservableCollection<PersonVM>` property of the `ViewModel`.

Is there a better way of doing this such that I don't have to duplicate the POCO class - just use it right away, and then, sort of dynamically add a "throw-away" property to it (that notifies changes) which will ultimately get bound to the view (CheckBox on a GridView column)?

POCO example:

```
public sealed class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
}
```

Comment: There is a better way, but not without lots of work https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mwinkle/2009/10/28/deep-dive-into-the-wf4-designer-data-model-modelitem-and-modelproperty/ I've actually created something like this, so that I can drop a poco inside of it and attach UI-centric properties, validation, etc.  It's pretty slick, but it's a TON of work, and requires a decent understanding of the DLR.  For you, probably better to just create a UI version and automap it back and forth.

Comment: This is one of the things that Fody is capable of doing -- injecting INPC. See https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged